# Error in Extending `texreg` for `pcce` models from the `plm` package

Tags: r, tidyverse, plm, texreg

Hello stackoverflow community, I am trying to extend `texreg` to other models, but I ended up with the error, **Error in validObject(.Object): invalid class "texreg" object: invalid object for slot "coef.names" in class "texreg": got class "NULL", should be or extend class "character"**. I do not understand the error message as well as how to get around it. Hope you could be of help.

Below is the reprex for the packages and data employed, the code for the extension I wrote, the model formular and the `pcce` models I fitted as well as the code I wrote for `texreg`.

```r
library(reprex)
library(plm)
library(texreg)
#> Version:  1.37.5
#> Date:     2020-06-17
#> Author:   Philip Leifeld (University of Essex)
#> 
#> Consider submitting praise using the praise or praise_interactive functions.
#> Please cite the JSS article in your publications -- see citation("texreg").


AT <- structure(list(country = c("Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", 
"Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", 
"Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", 
"Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", 
"Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", 
"Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", 
"Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", 
"South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", 
"South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", 
"South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", 
"South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", 
"South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", 
"South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", 
"South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", "Singapore", "Singapore", 
"Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", 
"Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", 
"Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", 
"Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", 
"Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", 
"Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", 
"Singapore"), ccode = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L), .Label = c("1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", 
"1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", 
"1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", 
"2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"), class = "factor"), rgg = c(0.7, 
11.1, 13.4, 8.5, 2.3, 3.8, 5.7, 6.2, 6.2, 6, 2.4, 4.3, 5.1, -5.9, 
2.5, 7.7, 0.6, 1.7, 3.1, 8.7, 7.4, 7, 6.5, 2.1, -2.5, 6.8, 4.8, 
1.7, 3.1, 2.8, 2.4, 2.2, 3.8, 7.7, 11.2, 12.5, 11.9, 7, 9.8, 
10.4, 6.2, 6.8, 9.2, 9.6, 7.6, 5.9, -5.5, 11.3, 8.4, 4.9, 7.7, 
3.1, 5.2, 4.3, 5.3, 5.8, 3, 0.8, 6.8, 3.7, 2.4, 3.2, 3.2, 2.8, 
2.9, 3.2, -0.6, 1.3, 10.8, 11.3, 10.2, 9.8, 6.7, 6.6, 11.5, 11.1, 
7.2, 7.5, 8.3, -2.2, 5.7, 9, -1.1, 3.9, 4.5, 9.8, 7.4, 9, 9, 
1.9, 0.1, 14.5, 6.3, 4.4, 4.8, 3.9, 2.9, 3, 3.7), hdi = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.781, 0.786, 0.791, 0.799, 0.804, 0.808, 0.811, 
0.816, 0.817, 0.821, 0.827, 0.835, 0.842, 0.851, 0.862, 0.871, 
0.883, 0.887, 0.896, 0.898, 0.901, 0.904, 0.911, 0.915, 0.923, 
0.927, 0.93, 0.933, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.728, 0.739, 0.746, 
0.756, 0.767, 0.778, 0.789, 0.8, 0.797, 0.808, 0.817, 0.824, 
0.832, 0.839, 0.847, 0.855, 0.862, 0.869, 0.874, 0.869, 0.884, 
0.888, 0.89, 0.893, 0.896, 0.898, 0.9, 0.903, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.718, 0.729, 0.74, 0.751, 0.763, 0.773, 0.782, 0.793, 0.798, 
0.809, 0.819, 0.822, 0.83, 0.838, 0.845, 0.868, 0.871, 0.878, 
0.883, 0.884, 0.909, 0.914, 0.92, 0.923, 0.928, 0.929, 0.93, 
0.932), ineq = c(38.5, 38.5, 38.7, 38.8, 39, 39.1, 39.2, 39.4, 
39.5, 39.7, 39.8, 39.9, 40, 40.1, 40.2, 40.3, 40.3, 40.4, 40.5, 
40.6, 40.6, 40.7, 40.7, 40.8, 40.9, 40.9, 40.9, 41, 41, 41, 41, 
41, 41, 30.6, 30.5, 30.3, 30.1, 29.9, 29.5, 29.1, 28.8, 28.8, 
28.9, 29.1, 29.5, 29.9, 30.5, 30.8, 30.7, 30.9, 30.8, 30.7, 30.8, 
30.9, 30.9, 31.3, 31.4, 31.5, 31.2, 31.2, 31, 31.1, 31.3, 31.7, 
32.3, 32.7, 37.1, 37.2, 37.3, 37.4, 37.6, 37.8, 38, 38.2, 38.3, 
38.4, 38.5, 38.6, 38.7, 38.8, 38.8, 38.9, 39, 39, 39.1, 39.2, 
39.3, 39.4, 39.5, 39.5, 39.5, 39.5, 39.3, 39.2, 39, 38.8, 38.7, 
38.6, 38.6), emp = c(96.5779467680608, 97.037037037037, 98.1684981684982, 
98.9130434782609, 98.9090909090909, 98.5454545454545, 98.2142857142857, 
98.2078853046595, 97.9020979020979, 97.9522184300341, 97, 97.1518987341772, 
97.8328173374613, 95.1219512195122, 93.6746987951807, 95.0536423448521, 
94.9114463280133, 92.679836433796, 92.0595533498759, 93.1877704395354, 
94.4089185671439, 95.2124979002184, 95.9859757612567, 96.4780600461894, 
94.7354042018414, 95.6709718282709, 96.5785423023953, 96.7161969224261, 
96.5993100049285, 96.703779287541, 96.6847714695634, 96.6072294074131, 
96.8732579942229, 96.0107747562853, 96.2087366592206, 96.92407989095, 
97.4861303744799, 97.4310603118238, 97.5511084740277, 97.7086058069579, 
97.6101338530181, 97.2282307963177, 97.5926652284762, 97.9811058360907, 
97.9946335263381, 97.4332933247161, 93.1860551826995, 93.7459554405103, 
95.5848494424631, 96.0152814179734, 96.7365764511357, 96.4370958642538, 
96.3387699626232, 96.2602243022177, 96.5201465201465, 96.7557800501006, 
96.839232617816, 96.3631925799365, 96.3014906234974, 96.6048288628934, 
96.7960901439044, 96.901332924774, 96.5009688478164, 96.4092365484477, 
96.3199358085929, 96.3132478016434, 95.8850931677019, 93.5334872979215, 
95.3348382242287, 96.7343976777939, 97.8245614035088, 98.3365323096609, 
98.0694980694981, 97.2839506172839, 97.3105134474328, 97.4010632014176, 
97.3127501429388, 97.0033296337403, 97.5479744136461, 96.7908902691511, 
95.4453441295547, 95.5748175182482, 96.5566037735849, 95.8028096182022, 
95.4936643169139, 95.5677014390025, 95.7544778641433, 96.5961219690837, 
97.1073312917389, 97.2175924351168, 95.9042904290429, 97.1714659268471, 
97.300052516141, 97.4091260634184, 97.3633011005604, 97.4340092896794, 
97.3799368526007, 97.201045523851, 97.076838939021), total = c(15.9202011096209, 
15.2642825978261, 13.8835753131415, 14.171521799986, 15.5469757911512, 
16.2006058337021, 15.9486863729186, 15.6059692740854, 17.0032284957751, 
16.1152020882272, 17.4536584742895, 17.4451762082705, 17.4616562021679, 
20.8186896901981, 21.6256036670214, 20.6063397335778, 20.4113562357415, 
20.5390063213912, 21.9111794752636, 19.9850563689254, 17.8123041515447, 
16.2881456160271, 15.2956584740567, 19.3831636785522, 18.5139928099829, 
18.0467390105003, 19.9356916507705, 19.6449391009293, 21.3882491038463, 
18.7657106953303, 19.515152525977, 19.8665196131373, 19.2677668365412, 
18.2838941361669, 16.7893360882124, 16.3493048436123, 15.8058314157684, 
17.3263966207143, 18.6222923203409, 18.6186845010184, 18.3122914122914, 
17.6746775640818, 18.5912487979543, 17.3210812243275, 18.3435250036441, 
20.4010801366055, 23.716320068772, 24.4802421159041, 19.4569224706369, 
20.2065482327053, 16.700663008306, 18.7523959085942, 18.529429377332, 
19.1724499236407, 19.942014804075, 18.7129529003629, 20.4577737365564, 
22.3441750459224, 18.9894052008633, 19.4864821822038, 20.0737248521191, 
19.7596765659499, 19.7692934080367, 20.2798469789636, 20.194744929226, 
20.1219895514415, 27.1840918725192, 29.2487692602775, 35.2956131835622, 
23.0338268873143, 22.3296755684575, 21.2650165583954, 21.3984158256604, 
19.5236899256874, 17.3444918988687, 13.9627690399078, 16.1672524244994, 
21.0982307785774, 16.7726977165494, 20.0459861341301, 19.0335889849647, 
19.1001660112035, 22.2476498614084, 18.859896102842, 18.630695181316, 
17.1356363728505, 14.7367573960416, 14.7642415560525, 13.8119800114872, 
16.6962801905864, 17.9157516410459, 14.505162068252, 14.6621876204514, 
14.2683860818447, 13.9857107463955, 14.6498327225184, 17.4691299276575, 
16.3177514024186, 16.1987329487883), hea = c(1.35331237219938, 
1.39012296139184, 1.28880456193846, 1.24068339281965, 1.37626166805798, 
1.57074299717504, 1.57889219147519, 1.72319886164745, 2.02200022129493, 
1.87633585265879, 2.21525309163951, 2.0779982244978, 2.08114858100801, 
2.45341250927843, 2.55943582311373, 2.44635331113771, 2.58730704193796, 
2.55669095480679, 2.72155993344309, 2.4449693951702, 2.23889528193326, 
2.13702588417475, 2.03682433987821, 2.14970889968708, 2.31352211397352, 
2.24563876572623, 2.34162001209659, 2.92441210588402, 3.16147602891075, 
2.54459614027403, 2.93643778040929, 2.66888504972291, 2.67698064963211, 
0.236004525777253, 0.244882039172693, 0.360438137376572, 0.327146663437084, 
0.320654264256361, 0.318014284356002, 0.330791507128968, 0.172120472120472, 
0.157947653488146, 0.113293775335722, 0.135709553464953, 0.162971140726297, 
0.171440799865865, 0.215430038684241, 0.218003745256285, 0.144252666832813, 
0.118242547996786, 0.0634604040847602, 0.183671397777552, 0.172493657253012, 
0.21954199487429, 0.217034282466762, 0.182249475570458, 0.189652461215032, 
0.234040352007972, 0.224707003842097, 0.190145385982894, 0.181722052891186, 
0.203688772351045, 0.193738819469011, 0.285099025319592, 0.246498752627846, 
0.242142199627368, 1.75729315195191, 1.18662489610639, 1.26658346045394, 
1.19269006536255, 1.04369737883831, 0.974814792664967, 1.33220752415799, 
1.1868354829337, 1.03829384670371, 1.01992469246953, 1.23231903781605, 
1.16968868285825, 1.12679317908881, 1.43560774061019, 1.27016256195849, 
0.978438835207565, 1.22710279451947, 1.05393723556448, 1.47056629854858, 
0.98600967942016, 0.857428757968938, 0.847036325559884, 0.834413768201352, 
1.02705000412387, 1.38266371458401, 1.17911249217105, 1.15633305279144, 
1.3051547956642, 1.53992474358164, 1.77338945762091, 2.1104556658128, 
2.23389203660304, 2.18195591534874), edu = c(2.65312254934295, 
2.74330336527591, 2.45103241554434, 2.55310028693401, 2.54534416027927, 
2.81984956264252, 2.87325008453341, 2.80291513283518, 2.78634413113806, 
2.80692929412599, 3.06860671207548, 3.13049941160683, 3.49761183328796, 
3.7878657655194, 4.03704577517346, 3.90369801592672, 4.01554110004829, 
4.28530355550314, 4.55895705233439, 4.13463239654687, 3.84279012127113, 
3.4545492037455, 3.26062725199848, 4.39212714357415, 3.51003016432172, 
3.41822362035926, 3.509612650755, 3.76032309324374, 3.57254928553223, 
3.26211667673302, 3.29269309671931, 3.3097482919481, 3.32610166994678, 
3.02821231798505, 2.85941683708967, 2.80014029029299, 2.79747486980744, 
2.97050547581935, 3.15933712534327, 2.59053812508371, 2.64220594220594, 
3.47574928737968, 3.3925363396587, 3.38288061481383, 3.44946819314709, 
3.58474748276988, 3.76492853879789, 3.66430240458711, 2.97298607931073, 
3.24234927575732, 2.7490588299609, 2.87150764600861, 2.81581860404086, 
2.87127924885304, 2.8407475525842, 2.79010832918372, 3.100804745037, 
3.22678676036798, 2.84860736095385, 2.95103335125591, 3.13121609897679, 
3.2157773045399, 3.21895640934146, 3.03928709200442, 3.08758213848554, 
3.17007447084711, 5.86792040797975, 5.30912345757944, 5.09406924605926, 
4.37646634181556, 4.03347323077971, 4.22818440744866, 4.89861016176806, 
4.34844701838364, 4.29210949704791, 3.16083934238965, 3.05389840681155, 
3.1391644992948, 3.15728013589295, 3.64737738976167, 3.80613781408793, 
4.01584779220318, 4.32510990329825, 4.40852687222882, 4.0866328879784, 
3.70111677990171, 3.18494067694719, 2.94340792680498, 2.87517282280681, 
3.11361852631013, 3.28434196157492, 3.04906516325946, 3.05526001613958, 
2.90699840616009, 3.0711239520434, 2.9243668158173, 2.86309338115704, 
2.88010695969337, 2.79654316073746), soc = c(0.923462544798927, 
0.818787201314646, 0.739528948274389, 0.760856253061796, 0.829285876906731, 
0.903475034886491, 0.93643825664787, 0.922384019592604, 1.00459132195235, 
1.06314692655566, 1.29047500462936, 1.48159464871895, 1.61467142068773, 
2.06094464195023, 2.21613405941897, 2.07304517903164, 2.24169695611827, 
2.45270904103085, 2.65248844365541, 2.52743272518526, 2.35545720102682, 
2.23101591045604, 2.11224432926489, 2.29858265392357, 2.43592718374924, 
2.28104881294713, 2.24076342902043, 2.25295389087896, 2.58859236638365, 
2.57039254337933, 2.70581416681955, 2.73621543797073, 2.66254989227665, 
0.958038173947265, 1.02011342792688, 1.01881328800878, 1.13880646723992, 
1.38093213762762, 1.50517066841166, 1.58800245714998, 1.6958485958486, 
1.64931512773111, 1.83412851298828, 1.68588843248973, 1.88401329576872, 
2.12484225946223, 2.75724795045537, 3.04581724475084, 2.96838227079479, 
2.60450427731102, 2.70547758860149, 3.10891904963785, 3.27605854084676, 
3.44516954344665, 3.67620772244274, 3.81789662502127, 4.12816832890537, 
4.47986916970099, 4.2605113278944, 4.32755347038009, 4.59089484327393, 
4.85108431789014, 5.0671530867463, 5.28346937106443, 5.31905360104174, 
5.40600846043211, 0.429046719847907, 0.465443385972764, 0.453011602644109, 
0.462952064844676, 0.480134846382388, 0.448534413802899, 0.461045662284052, 
0.449372356090042, 0.66391414508327, 0.399625038594878, 0.802772633775124, 
2.22479247830962, 0.300054574632045, 0.147354046546371, 0.29941617470825, 
0.677868512532007, 2.76328292742272, 0.787599305999452, 0.402758648123194, 
0.554699300098381, 0.299860560049472, 1.19087417959595, 0.562387396236158, 
2.04738238467426, 2.23806266575464, 1.12141322262519, 1.57267069626841, 
1.7475661167574, 1.4740866149498, 1.59293982998783, 1.8452730832712, 
1.44852649425049, 0.998468881705865), hou = c(3.33948975029866, 
2.96559565096926, 2.84499918462857, 3.14730736930506, 3.37956287470593, 
3.52217419420714, 3.19838995226262, 2.86913368692019, 3.03009720543947, 
3.19254826063608, 3.16976856830888, 3.52614736668249, 3.32350101818755, 
4.62249482361214, 5.31283152534158, 4.56164144924004, 3.79769926321319, 
3.26837354249962, 3.42444987502676, 2.66631433715353, 2.26594671151633, 
2.10343426119383, 1.99672150214811, 3.92248960021365, 2.56354546796887, 
2.58876156033895, 3.16615230326246, 2.46512251240637, 3.32291230671022, 
2.5053484394946, 2.56934136130894, 2.51069677918242, 2.62512011538593, 
0.883633412042503, 0.825936623727098, 0.964315904962319, 0.767152113358363, 
1.49564431128835, 1.98208023624557, 1.81002350919815, 1.41599511599512, 
1.19907602604713, 1.32616177139023, 1.50801643036968, 1.69121987005322, 
1.47298776021673, 1.65077514756946, 2.17322224615946, 1.03938650261558, 
1.72545013848946, 0.316410006711766, 1.03813749081942, 1.28759304970547, 
1.43591117970087, 1.45231485832111, 1.31636449601445, 1.21840226681909, 
1.40747769295117, 0.932246755509102, 0.918544049363787, 1.10019266565073, 
0.846537733961408, 0.861459532804083, 0.864102757722402, 0.819862548940716, 
1.64150076521293, 1.13042249540766, 4.18899047375487, 3.42763370776129, 
2.72082421160833, 2.12655469195604, 1.30074980002841, 1.08292120676022, 
1.30625772551105, 1.2122266259268, 0.921641040286098, 1.31553839985138, 
1.58880790189688, 1.51580510996471, 2.42550596419151, 2.56424941874838, 
2.05009251732084, 2.33386271047674, 2.02860723018699, 2.69562385325663, 
2.26672057587372, 1.7742548153726, 1.56242692362989, 1.68304624635412, 
1.22036828251638, 1.21053389494906, 1.31281348773162, 1.25998438012031, 
0.998806345000793, 0.773135293652596, 0.90881541173672, 0.801687873322594, 
1.01291891058634, 1.17931417456033), eco = c(3.0019861773781, 
2.99744268330356, 2.75233157402925, 2.75233571278606, 3.48448053426425, 
2.96041659575916, 3.00732229157161, 3.2050285662293, 3.93357208353555, 
3.30150431211539, 3.29282298134663, 2.85294299812127, 2.92916716869486, 
3.61136070633277, 2.92889849727236, 3.68126827568727, 3.39123273652643, 
3.76770640872369, 4.18813545969543, 4.08618708849014, 3.56569000619634, 
2.94601859445998, 2.53520205287759, 3.27738952038873, 4.05497681174269, 
3.80418750548884, 5.23590928593953, 4.78223752969354, 5.27123118544829, 
4.2708755069126, 4.26042830695332, 4.8497552698977, 4.17898197771275, 
3.99805686737505, 3.04178701692986, 2.88863109048724, 3.06883553348674, 
3.27543742450927, 3.79704357455662, 3.84867281569989, 3.43015873015873, 
3.51171364014746, 4.18073820294551, 4.68429839671393, 5.24874605416281, 
5.3683407019123, 6.8063109996917, 6.73385893972789, 4.90366991061245, 
5.91116561834841, 3.77500202933119, 3.5697694553749, 3.42378444259121, 
3.57408518772512, 3.59770744176495, 3.45100243176726, 3.81055027371381, 
4.51579241408931, 3.59947050198879, 3.49519042329632, 3.38883505817675, 
3.25882046677045, 3.04185302351246, 3.35158723016918, 3.17265896268545, 
2.54197558182494, 4.80686474751757, 5.81037018093472, 5.50778902602505, 
3.68399990584026, 4.45571947866209, 3.57182904858375, 2.29718681731066, 
2.25301756615007, 1.99386356670375, 1.24616253334458, 1.66186544185699, 
3.05918578593697, 2.87981790570379, 3.86986741053713, 2.45767755995392, 
3.83258867141576, 3.36105165208413, 2.31840826307085, 1.98706697229916, 
2.07337454376396, 1.70671433778957, 1.57065478159801, 1.35451921116094, 
2.07798489206458, 2.92208181829091, 2.12835853953842, 2.26329458198055, 
1.92392346808525, 1.60523405190318, 1.71887106060716, 3.74753125619179, 
2.66953165811053, 2.85793126766109), gen = c(2.28886787889448, 
1.97515294537279, 1.71279770764145, 1.61815907341312, 1.74186081809213, 
2.06817330928151, 2.15460533601478, 2.02522623619552, 2.32896476699945, 
2.03209833623527, 2.42232019141392, 2.36496892871152, 2.24811943957291, 
2.32027190686409, 2.49427429152884, 1.94085836197506, 2.29225927265956, 
2.12180143848071, 2.247608558817, 2.18611350933104, 1.78787288660706, 
1.74503492531019, 1.65875514006916, 1.70338046497572, 1.8374019508873, 
1.87493103766638, 1.81211002724317, 1.79390974930034, 1.82097502461061, 
1.89088077238767, 1.95298297112931, 2.05829438515953, 2.06754421204495, 
1.72262396694215, 1.68391979928739, 1.53114264645048, 1.42659258810706, 
1.53552366107276, 1.57938891592141, 1.64559768325859, 1.78962148962149, 
1.68863086808146, 1.77652308082385, 1.84245395521399, 1.87510006475833, 
1.9940389519851, 2.33471432397095, 2.12126924415425, 1.02097126855181, 
0.970409236609986, 1.04926298641348, 1.10262549784144, 0.890868645914883, 
0.87451242772713, 0.923218591062165, 1.05479671552655, 1.00735000755924, 
1.27589740288217, 1.02161542258224, 1.02942019264802, 1.11220562520372, 
1.2503172434306, 1.06543554220541, 1.03225509167438, 1.12162389770652, 
0.938171644990446, 3.83059077421095, 3.53430087590307, 5.19114316091157, 
2.44226830818484, 2.11804166276486, 2.09764594188489, 2.7421494913755, 
2.40814336578664, 2.47217870956726, 2.07693755557431, 2.40579610247582, 
4.51572120035744, 2.23381805679009, 2.18769695837905, 2.50842606414176, 
2.31325007831315, 2.53903745425491, 2.78069481224444, 2.61233734268794, 
2.6021842042351, 2.31984775130926, 2.33324730169563, 2.57021891200676, 
2.85275081087314, 2.23768765525435, 1.86809140432887, 1.63849939440485, 
1.76660939882566, 1.88233589449823, 1.09197215977324, 1.04488408269238, 
1.00824446785133, 1.12956085472994), eogdp = c(84.0797988903791, 
84.7357174021739, 86.1164246868585, 85.828478200014, 84.4530242088487, 
83.7993941662979, 84.0513136270814, 84.3940307259146, 82.9967715042249, 
83.8847979117728, 82.5463415257105, 82.5548237917295, 82.5383437978321, 
79.1813103098019, 78.3743963329786, 79.3936602664222, 79.5886437642585, 
79.4609936786088, 78.0888205247364, 80.0149436310746, 82.1876958484553, 
83.7118543839729, 84.7043415259433, 80.6168363214478, 81.4860071900171, 
81.9532609894997, 80.0643083492295, 80.3550608990707, 78.6117508961537, 
81.2342893046697, 80.484847474023, 80.1334803868627, 80.7322331634588, 
81.7161058638331, 83.2106639117876, 83.6506951563877, 84.1941685842316, 
82.6736033792857, 81.3777076796591, 81.3813154989816, 81.6877085877086, 
82.3253224359182, 81.4087512020457, 82.6789187756725, 81.6564749963559, 
79.5989198633945, 76.283679931228, 75.5197578840959, 80.5430775293631, 
79.7934517672947, 83.2993369916939, 81.2476040914058, 81.470570622668, 
80.8275500763593, 80.057985195925, 81.2870470996371, 79.5422262634436, 
77.6558249540776, 81.0105947991367, 80.5135178177962, 79.9262751478809, 
80.2403234340501, 80.2307065919633, 79.7201530210364, 79.805255070774, 
79.8780104485585, 72.8159081274808, 70.7512307397225, 64.7043868164378, 
76.9661731126857, 77.6703244315425, 78.7349834416046, 78.6015841743396, 
80.4763100743126, 82.6555081011313, 86.0372309600922, 83.8327475755005, 
78.9017692214226, 83.2273022834506, 79.9540138658699, 80.9664110150353, 
80.8998339887965, 77.7523501385916, 81.140103897158, 81.369304818684, 
82.8643636271495, 85.2632426039584, 85.2357584439475, 86.1880199885128, 
83.3037198094136, 82.084248358954, 85.494837931748, 85.3378123795486, 
85.7316139181553, 86.0142892536045, 85.3501672774816, 82.5308700723425, 
83.6822485975814, 83.8012670512117), pgr = c(1.509110516, 1.6213902295, 
1.6840910467, 1.6816633881, 1.5869438622, 1.4360091106, 1.2508510172, 
1.1094188819, 1.078456365, 1.1952400662, 1.4004867984, 1.652058818, 
1.831424167, 1.8414430378, 1.6301663285, 1.2776218859, 0.8808217054, 
0.5535625205, 0.3413561827, 0.2951317175, 0.3702200047, 0.4789989929, 
0.5561328207, 0.6098892543, 0.6197244432, 0.6001328504, 0.5764594052, 
0.57280062, 0.5932969652, 0.6452466267, 0.7167856753, 0.7976599816, 
0.8628867461, 1.2532149586, 1.1227597999, 1.0161254853, 0.9552097325, 
0.9565979715, 1.0004015543, 1.0539528739, 1.0893653533, 1.1041073905, 
1.0880762788, 1.0485889347, 1.0072232606, 0.9680274351, 0.9150179132, 
0.8463611921, 0.7675877228, 0.6877818726, 0.6129743212, 0.5430073031, 
0.4806677607, 0.4272573231, 0.3676520016, 0.3153014652, 0.3006499971, 
0.3349077606, 0.4008131798, 0.4842668548, 0.5498157446, 0.5678559982, 
0.5194159042, 0.4242950221, 0.315027195, 0.2213209398, 2.2820293047, 
2.0814657296, 1.9548188026, 1.9790627141, 2.2029075379, 2.5442677753, 
2.8845436226, 3.1267852874, 3.2639875453, 3.2703938822, 3.1771131233, 
3.1328857964, 3.0841213228, 2.8530008352, 2.4061158751, 1.8571323685, 
1.1911778884, 0.6663059572, 0.6028947894, 1.1551422028, 2.0963008677, 
3.1527930213, 3.9267025032, 4.2163984719, 3.9174727146, 3.2595383154, 
2.5489099273, 1.9906218323, 1.5571124019, 1.3096761134, 1.1965670748, 
1.0934355495, 0.9579125335)), row.names = c("1-1985", "1-1986", 
"1-1987", "1-1988", "1-1989", "1-1990", "1-1991", "1-1992", "1-1993", 
"1-1994", "1-1995", "1-1996", "1-1997", "1-1998", "1-1999", "1-2000", 
"1-2001", "1-2002", "1-2003", "1-2004", "1-2005", "1-2006", "1-2007", 
"1-2008", "1-2009", "1-2010", "1-2011", "1-2012", "1-2013", "1-2014", 
"1-2015", "1-2016", "1-2017", "2-1985", "2-1986", "2-1987", "2-1988", 
"2-1989", "2-1990", "2-1991", "2-1992", "2-1993", "2-1994", "2-1995", 
"2-1996", "2-1997", "2-1998", "2-1999", "2-2000", "2-2001", "2-2002", 
"2-2003", "2-2004", "2-2005", "2-2006", "2-2007", "2-2008", "2-2009", 
"2-2010", "2-2011", "2-2012", "2-2013", "2-2014", "2-2015", "2-2016", 
"2-2017", "3-1985", "3-1986", "3-1987", "3-1988", "3-1989", "3-1990", 
"3-1991", "3-1992", "3-1993", "3-1994", "3-1995", "3-1996", "3-1997", 
"3-1998", "3-1999", "3-2000", "3-2001", "3-2002", "3-2003", "3-2004", 
"3-2005", "3-2006", "3-2007", "3-2008", "3-2009", "3-2010", "3-2011", 
"3-2012", "3-2013", "3-2014", "3-2015", "3-2016", "3-2017"), class = c("pdata.frame", 
"data.frame"), index = structure(list(ccode = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), year = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L), .Label = c("1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", 
"1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", 
"1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", 
"2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", 
"2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-99L), class = c("pindex", "data.frame")))




HDIMF1 <- diff(hdi) ~ diff(hea) + diff(log(edu)) + diff(soc) + diff(hou) + diff(log(eco)) +                                   diff(log(gen)) + diff(eogdp) 

               
HDIMF2 <- diff(hdi) ~ diff(log(total)) + diff(eogdp)




SMHDI1 <- pcce(HDIMF1, data = AT, model="p", trend = FALSE)


SMHDI2 <- pcce(HDIMF2, data = AT, model="p", trend = FALSE)




extract.pcce <- function(model, include.r.squared = TRUE,
      include.N = TRUE, ...) {

  
s <- summary(model, ...)
names <- rownames(s$coef)
co <- s$coef[1]
se <- s$coef[2]
pval <- s$coef[4]

gof <- numeric()
gof.names <- character()
gof.decimal <- logical()
if (include.r.squared == TRUE) {
  rs <- s$r.squared
  gof <- c(gof, rs)
  gof.names <- c(gof.names, "HPY \\ R$^2$")
  gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE)
}
if (include.N == TRUE) {
  n <- nobs(model)
  gof <- c(gof, n)
  gof.names <- c(gof.names, "Num.\\ obs.")
  gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, FALSE)
}

tr <- createTexreg(
    coef.names = names,
    coef = co,
    se = se,
    pvalues = pval,
    gof.names = gof.names,
    gof = gof,
    gof.decimal = gof.decimal
)
return(tr)
}

setMethod("extract", signature = className("pcce", "plm"), 
    definition = extract.pcce)




MPT <- texreg(list(SMHDI1, SMHDI2),
              custom.model.names = c("HDI M1", "HDI M2"),
              caption = "Estimations of the Study Models.",
              caption.above = TRUE,
              label = "table:MPT",
              groups = list("Independent Variables" = 2:8, "Control Variables" = 9),
              custom.coef.names = c("Intercept", "hea", "edu", "soc", "hou", "eco", "gen", "total",                                         "eogdp"),
              stars = c(0.01, 0.05, 0.10),
              custom.note = "\n\\item Note: ***, ** and * represents the significance level of 1% 5%,                                and 10%,respectively.\\\\\n\\item M1 refers to models with various                                      G items and M2 refers to models with only total.\n" ,
              single.row = TRUE, 
              digits = 4,
              dcolumn = TRUE,
              no.margin = TRUE,
              center = TRUE,
              sideways = TRUE,
              table = TRUE,
              booktabs = TRUE,
              threeparttable = TRUE,
              scalebox = 0.7,
              use.packages = FALSE,
              float.pos = "h!")
#> Error in validObject(.Object): invalid class "texreg" object: invalid object for slot "coef.names" in class "texreg": got class "NULL", should be or extend class "character"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

In the `summary` for `pcce` there is `GOF statistics` on Residual Sum of Squares (RSS) and Total Sum of Squares (TSS) , but I could not figure them out from the output from `str`. Would wish to include them in the `GOF statistics` session of the `texreg` table output.

Thank you for the helping hand.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that your attempt at extracting the coefficient names from the summary resulted in `NULL`, rather than a `character` vector. The reason is that you tried to access the slot `s$coef`, which does not exist in the model. Instead, you should extract the relevant coefficients, names, SE, and p-values from `s$CoefTable`.

You should also avoid putting the coefficient names into an object called `names` because that's also the name of a function, and it's easy to get confused if you overwrite existing functions locally.

The RSS and TSS seem to be stored in the summary under `s$ssr` and `s$tss`. I have included it in the method below.

Ideally, also re-use argument names that were used in other `extract` functions. In this case, use `include.nobs` instead of `include.N`. That will unify the code and documentation, especially when you supply multiple models of different kinds.

Here is the revised method:

```r
extract.pcce <- function(model,
                         include.r.squared = TRUE,
                         include.sumsquares = TRUE,
                         include.nobs = TRUE,
                         ...) {

  s <- summary(model, ...)
  coefnames <- rownames(s$CoefTable)
  co <- s$CoefTable[, 1]
  se <- s$CoefTable[, 2]
  pval <- s$CoefTable[, 4]

  gof <- numeric()
  gof.names <- character()
  gof.decimal <- logical()
  if (isTRUE(include.r.squared)) {
    rs <- s$r.squared
    gof <- c(gof, rs)
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "HPY R$^2$")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE)
  }
  if (isTRUE(include.sumsquares)) {
    gof <- c(gof, s$ssr, s$tss)
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "RSS", "TSS")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, TRUE, TRUE)
  }
  if (isTRUE(include.nobs)) {
    n <- nobs(model)
    gof <- c(gof, n)
    gof.names <- c(gof.names, "Num. obs.")
    gof.decimal <- c(gof.decimal, FALSE)
  }

  tr <- createTexreg(
    coef.names = coefnames,
    coef = co,
    se = se,
    pvalues = pval,
    gof.names = gof.names,
    gof = gof,
    gof.decimal = gof.decimal
  )
  return(tr)
}

setMethod("extract", signature = className("pcce", "plm"),
          definition = extract.pcce)
```

There were also a few bugs in your function call. You provided nine instead of eight replacement coefficient names. You did not escape the percentage signs in the custom note. The `no.margin` argument created an overlap between the columns. And the group indices referred to nine instead of eight coefficient rows. I have fixed this for you as well:

```r
MPT <- texreg(list(SMHDI1, SMHDI2),
              custom.model.names = c("HDI M1", "HDI M2"),
              caption = "Estimations of the Study Models.",
              caption.above = TRUE,
              label = "table:MPT",
              groups = list("Independent Variables" = 1:7, "Control Variables" = 8),
              custom.coef.names = c("hea", "edu", "soc", "hou", "eco", "gen", "total", "eogdp"),
              stars = c(0.01, 0.05, 0.10),
              custom.note = "\n\\item Note: ***, ** and * represents the significance level of 1\\%, 5\\%, and 10\\%, respectively.\\\\\n\\item M1 refers to models with various G items and M2 refers to models with only total.\n" ,
              single.row = TRUE,
              digits = 4,
              dcolumn = TRUE,
              no.margin = FALSE,
              center = TRUE,
              sideways = TRUE,
              table = TRUE,
              booktabs = TRUE,
              threeparttable = TRUE,
              scalebox = 0.7,
              use.packages = FALSE,
              float.pos = "h!")
MPT
```

I would recommend using the placeholder `%stars` inside the custom note to re-insert the original stars note as part of your custom note. It has a nicer formatting.

You may also want to think about rescaling your dependent variable to avoid such small coefficients.

Comment: Hi Philip, thank you for your quick response. I'm very much grateful. Hope you would include the 'pcce' model in the next version of 'texreg'